# Rails Tutorial 9.3 failed test updating User authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, railstutorial.org

I am having a problem with the Rails Tutorial (rails 3).  I'm currently on 9.28 rSpec tests and I have been in constant search to figure out what I did to make these two errors.

```
 user@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ bundle exec rspec spec/
 ......................F.F............................................

 Failures:

 1) Authentication authorization in the Users controller visiting the edit page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_3::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x9685354>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:75:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2) Authentication authorization in the Users controller submitting to the update action 
 Failure/Error: before { put user_path(user) }
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_3::Nested_2::Nested_3:0x9b12034>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:85:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 10.86 seconds
 69 examples, 2 failures

 Failed examples:

 rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:76 # Authentication authorization in the Users controller visiting the edit page 
 rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:86 # Authentication authorization in the Users controller submitting to the update action
```

This is the authentication spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before{ click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')}

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector ('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end



    describe "valid information" do
      let (:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }


      it { should have_selector('title',       text:    full_title(user.name)) }
      it { should have_link('Users',       href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',       href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',     href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',          href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in',    href: signin_path) }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do

          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            expect(page).to have_selector('title', text: ('Edit user'))

          end
        end
      end
    end

    describe "in the Users controller" do

      describe "visiting the edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
      end

      describe "visiting the user index" do
        before { visit users_path }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
      end

      describe "submitting to the update action" do
        before { put user_path(user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
      end
    end


    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
        before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Really I have been trying to figure this out for quite sometime, if it is possible to walk through explanation ( if it is not typo ) would be awesome.  Starting to grasp Rails but not quite there.

Comment: If you get your indentation right, it will be a lot clearer (both for you and those wanting to help you). Use two spaces per indentation and use the `{}` button in StackOverflow to code-quote your entire block of code.

Comment: I attempted to fix the indented code for authorization, thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reindent the messy spec code, you can see that you are missing the user definition in your `describe "in the Users controller"` block.

Seeing that you are using the `user` in all three `describe` blocks in the Authorization, I'd move it one level up, so you'll end up with:

```
describe "authorization" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  describe "for non-signed-in users" do
    ...
  end

  describe "in the Users controller" do
    ...
  end

  describe "as wrong user" do
    let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
    before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you mechanicalfish.

After cleaning up my code in line as well as on stackoverflow, I had an end that was ending the for_non-signed-in_users block, thus not declaring user in the code after.  I also did your fix, moving user up a class/nest/tier(is that what it would be called?) and it worked the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  If someone could give him recognition for the answer, that would be great.

Comment: People call it describe block, don't know if it has a better name because I don't use rspec too often. Also you should be able to accept the answer.